# How to solve Hibernate mapping exception for Set<Path> in java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to save directories to the DB for my file path tree, but I got this error when initializing Hibernate:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [hibernate-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.nio.file.Path, at table: BasePlan_selectedPaths, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(selected_paths)]
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086335/javafx-checkboxtreeitempath-selecting-root-item-error?noredirect=1#comment85194684_49086335) is my filePathTree:

```
@Column(name = "selected_paths")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Path.class)
private Set<Path> selectedPaths;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a converter class. After that I modified my fields. Hibernate create a table that will save paths like a string.

```
public class PathConverter implements AttributeConverter<Path, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Path path) {
        return path.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Path convertToEntityAttribute(String path) {
        return Paths.get(path);
    }
}

@Column(name = "selected_paths")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Path.class)
@Convert(converter = PathConverter.class)
private Set<Path> selectedPaths;

@Column(name = "unselected_paths")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Path.class)
@Convert(converter = PathConverter.class)
private Set<Path> unSelectedPaths;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save the Path of the directories and sub directories ?
What is the datatype of column: *selected_paths*. My guess is ***varchar***

In that case, you can map the path as String type in Java.

I think (correct me if I am wrong), Java is not able to determine the mapping between *nio* Path and corresponding datatype in DB.

While fetching the data back from DB, you can get it as **String** and easily use it as ***Path***

Comment: there is no any db yet.

Comment: Well if you have not configured any database and there is no table, it cannot map the field to a Columns.
**@Column** annotation is placed in an **@Entity** class, which represents the table of DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the field as `String` and use `Path` in a getter.

```
@Column(name = "selected_paths")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Path.class)
private Set<String> selectedPaths;

public Set<Path> getSelectedPaths() {
    return selectedPaths.stream().map(Paths::get).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```